# soap:address location attribute - Best Practices

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

What are the best practice to specify the soap:address location in wsdl:port so that one do not have to change this location for different environments (DEV/UAT/PROD)?

Comment: How are you building your webservices? I use JAX-WS and it figures out the correct endpoint in the WSDL automatically.

Comment: I am building WSDL statically. Using CXF to generate the code.

Comment: I don't know much about CXF. You might want to take a look at this though http://blog.progs.be/92/cxf-ws-client-dynamic-endpoint-and-loading-wsdl-from-the-classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any "best practice", but in my opinion, the best option is to set the location to a generic domain for this services and the port to point to the load balancer of the server, so you would have something like this in your WSDL:

```
<service name="EventRouter">
    <port name="EventRouterPort" binding="tns:EventRouterBinding">
        <soap:address
            location="http://esb.yourcompany.com:8888/EventManagement/BusinessService/EventRouterV1" />
    </port>
</service>
```

Then you modify the host files of the servers where the services will be deployed to map the IP address with the domain name you created, for instance: 127.0.0.1  esb.yourcompany.com

Create a load balancer at some specific port like 8888 to send the requests to the server nodes.

This way, it doesn't matter where the services are deployed, the address will work in every environment.